# KeyListener ignores if-statements

Tags: java, if-statement, keylistener

In this code:

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    boolean spacePressed = false;


if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    if(spacePressed == false){
    spacePressed = true;
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    }       
  }
}
```

I am trying to have space only print out "Hello world" once, then switch `spacePressed` to true and not do anything more from that point onward.

Using System prints I've managed to find out that it does change `spacePressed` to `true` after I've pressed it, but for some reason I can press space again and once more print out "Hello world".

In short, the compiler seems to ignore the if statement and just continue reading, which isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: the spacePressed variable should act like a local variable the way you build the code, and will be initiated as false every time, followed by beeing set to true, followed by getting destroyed because it´s local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `spacePressed` is a local variable, on the next call it is initialized with `false` again. Solution: Move it to a field of the `KeyManager` class:

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{
    private boolean spacePressed = false;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            if(this.spacePressed == false){
                this.spacePressed = true;
                System.out.println("Hello world");
            }               
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would advise OP to use `!this.spacePressed` instead of `== false`.

Comment: I would even advise OP to collapse the `if` to `if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !this.spacePressed){`

Comment: yes.. it's always good to mention code improvements when exist.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `spacePressed` is declared inside the method. Every time the method executes, it gets re-declared and initialized to `false`.

Declare it outside:

```
public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{

    boolean spacePressed = false;

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {


        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            if(spacePressed == false){
            spacePressed = true;
            System.out.println("Hello world");
            }       
          }
        }
```

Please note that `spacePressed == false` can be written as `!spacePressed`:

```
if(!spacePressed){
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel really stupid now that you've explained it.  Thanks for your help!